# Recursively compare directories with summary on different contents without examining file contents' differences

Tags: diff, recursive

I want to compare the contents of two directories, recursively, showing which files are missing from one or the other, and which files have different content. But I don't want output on the differences within the files, just whether they are different or not. There won't be any links to worry about.

I hope this isn't a duplicate, I've trawled through examples and can't find an answer to this. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually this looks already good:

```
diff -rq dirA dirB
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `diff -rq` doesn't account for [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) in file names. This causes problems, because my external SSD from SanDisk uses different byte codes in Unicode file names than my Mac laptop.

For example, my MacBook has the following files:

```
tmp/Česky.txt
tmp/Česky/README.txt
```

My SSD has the following *identical* files:

```
/Volumes/MySSD/Česky.txt
/Volumes/MySSD/Česky/README.txt
```

The names look exactly identical in browser, but on my machine they are actually different. Giving different bytecodes in Python:

```
# python3
>>> 'Česky'.encode()
b'C\xcc\x8cesky'
>>> 'Česky'.encode()
b'\xc4\x8cesky'
```

When I run `diff -rq tmp/ /Volumes/MySSD/`, I get:

```
Only in /Volumes/MySSD/: Česky
Only in /Volumes/MySSD/: Česky.txt
Only in tmp/: Česky
Only in tmp/: Česky.txt
```

Even though I just copied these file from laptop to the external drive! The contents of files are identical.

To avoid same issue, you can use [this Python script](https://gist.github.com/amakukha/f489cbde2afd32817f8e866cf4abe779) for comparing directories.

Comment: Why would a storage device have any say regarding what character encoding is used? Surely it just stores bytes? I assume this happens because the two disks use different filesystems.

Comment: @runeks, I guess so.